# Table contains more columns than expected (Expecting 3 columns) in visualization GeoChart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Hello i'm New to visualization GeoChart.
i'm using this Geochart :- https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

Problem :-

```
Table contains more columns than expected (Expecting 3 columns)
```

My Code :-

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrOfChart);       
          var options = {
            width: "100%",
            height: "440",
             
          };
          var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('compare-artist-map'));
          chart.draw(data, options);`
```

value in arrofChart Like :-

```
["Andorra", 0, 0, 0]
["Argentina", 0, 0, 0]
["Australia", "5", 0, 0]
["Austria", 0, 0, 0]
["Belgium", 0, 0, 0]
["Bosnia & Herzegovina", 0, 0, 0]
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

see the [data format specification](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#data-format) for the `GeoChart`

there are three data formats you can use,
each specifies the number of columns required and the data type of each...

1. [regions mode format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#regions-mode-format)
   this format takes two data table columns
   Region location (string), Region color (number)
   `['string', number]`
2. [markers mode format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#markers-mode-format)
   there are two options for this format
   a. Marker address (string), Marker color (number), Marker size (number)
   `['string', number, number]`
   b. Marker latitude (number), Marker longitude (number), Marker color (number), Marker size (number)
   `[number, number, number, number]`
3. [text mode format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#text-mode-format)
   this format takes two data table columns
   Text label (string), Text size (number)
   `['string', number]`

none of the above formats take the format you have provided --> `['string', number, number, number]`
which is why you received the error

Comment: Thanks ['string', number, number, number] Possible Or Not ? @WhiteHat